# Errors in PHPUnit itself

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework, ant, phpunit

```
    PHP Notice:  Please no longer include "PHPUnit/Framework.php". in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework.php on line 50

Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Runner_StandardTestSuiteLoader' not found in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php on line 434
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_Runner_StandardTestSuiteLoader' not found in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php on line 434
/var/www/nrka2/build/build.xml:30: exec returned: 255
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Hello I got this error in the latest phpUnit version. Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your inclusion to [PHPUnit/Autoload.php](http://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/detail?id=1641).

Comment: Where do you change the inclusion?

Answer (score 1):

Look in your folder that contains your tests.

For example, in Symfony2, there is a Tests folder under each bundle folder. Then you have to browse through the sub directories until you find the test file

e.g. login_databaseTest.php

You will see a line
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework.php';

Use a good IDE that has a search feature and search your entire project.

I originally though this was some file in the PHPUnit directory, under PHP. Not so. The files needing modified are generated test files that include this line needing modified.